# How to copy few files from one folder to another folder in php and delete them in source folder

Tags: php

How to copy files from one folder to another folder in php and delete them in source folder ?

I have two folder `$incoming_file_path = /home/xmlcontainer` and `$processing_file_path = home/process_file`. I am looping through all files in `$incoming_file_path  = home/xmlcontainer` and than copying it into `$processing_file_path = home/process_file`.

After executing below code I am not able to copy the content of files but just the name of the files also am not able to delete files which I have copies to destination folder from source folder using `unlink`, I am surely using unlink in wrong way and would certainly appreciate any guidance on it.

Code

```
foreach( glob($incoming_file_path.'/*')as $key => $value ) {
    copy($incoming_file_path.$value,$processing_file_path.$value);
    unlink($incoming_file_path.$value); 
    }
```

Comment: +1 because ur question I resolved by big issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, just use [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) if you intend to move the files.

Your loop should look like this:

```
foreach (glob($incoming_file_path . '/*') as $value) {
  rename($value, $processing_file_path . '/' . basename($value))
}
```

Inability to read file contents and/or delete a file is often a simple permissions problem. Check if the owner of your PHP process can read and write to both `$incoming_file_path` and `$processing_file_path`. You may want to run `chmod -R u+rwx` (or `chmod -R o+rwx`) on both `$incoming_file_path` and `$processing_file_path`.